# App is working fine in debug build but not working in production

Tags: android, rest, android-studio

I am facing problem with my app in live environment. Everything works fine when I generate a debug build for testing and test it thoroughly, but when I uploaded my application on google play console and then in the production app I am facing many problems. For example when I try to login into the app, after entering the correct credentials and clicking the login button a loader is generated and after loading for few seconds it stops on the login screen itself. Ideally the user should be able to login, but the screen is not redirecting the user to home screen.

I have checked hitting the login api url in postman and it works fine. I have also checked the logcat by attaching the production app through usb cable and the logcat shows that api is being called and i can see the response also.

What could be the possible reason please suggest..

This is the retrofit code which is being used for calling a rest api for login purpose.

```
    private void userLoginApi() {
        if (Util.isConnectingToInternet(getActivity())) {
            CommonMethods.showLoading(getActivity());

            MultipartBody.Builder builder = new MultipartBody.Builder();
            builder.setType(MultipartBody.FORM);
            builder.addFormDataPart(Constants.MOBILE, mobileEt.getText().toString());
            builder.addFormDataPart(Constants.PASSWORD, passwordEt.getText().toString());
            builder.addFormDataPart(Constants.DEVICE_ID, token);
            builder.addFormDataPart(Constants.LANGUAGE, SharedPref.getSharedPreferences(getActivity(), Constants.LANGUAGE));

            MultipartBody requestBody = builder.build();
            RetrofitClient.getAPIService().user_login(requestBody).enqueue(new Callback<RetroResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<RetroResponse> call, Response<RetroResponse> response) {
                    CommonMethods.dismissLoading();
                    try {
                        if (response.body().getStatus() == 200) {

                            Pref.with(getApplicationContext()).getSharedPreferences().edit().putBoolean("isLogin", false)
                                    .putString("admin_id", response.body().getId())
                                    .putString("first_name", response.body().getData().getFirstName())
                                    .putString("email", response.body().getData().getEmail())
                                    .apply();

                            userID = response.body().getData().getUser_id();

                            SharedPref.setSharedPreference(getActivity(), Constants.USER_ID, response.body().getData().getUser_id());
                            SharedPref.setSharedPreference(getActivity(), Constants.ADMIN_ID, response.body().getId());
                            SharedPref.setSharedPreference(getActivity(), Constants.FIRST_NAME, response.body().getData().getFirstName());
                            SharedPref.setSharedPreference(getActivity(), Constants.LAST_NAME, response.body().getData().getLastName());
                            SharedPref.setSharedPreference(getActivity(), Constants.EMAIL, response.body().getData().getEmail());
                            SharedPref.setSharedPreference(getActivity(), Constants.MOBILE, response.body().getData().getMobile());
                            SharedPref.setSharedPreference(getActivity(), Constants.USER_MOBILE, response.body().getData().getMobile());
                            SharedPref.setSharedPreference(getActivity(), Constants.PROFILE_CITY, response.body().getData().getCity());
                            

                           
                            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), UserHomeActivity.class)
                                    .putExtra("screen_type", "")
                                    .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
                            getActivity().finish();

                        } else if (response.body().getStatus() == 204) {
                            Util.ShowToastMessage(getActivity(), response.body().getMessage());

                            mobileEt.setText("");
                            passwordEt.setText("");
                            captchaCheck.setChecked(false);
                            captchaVerified = false;

                        } else if (response.body().getStatus() == 401) {
                            Util.ShowToastMessage(getActivity(), "Something went wrong");
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<RetroResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                    CommonMethods.dismissLoading();
                }
            });
        } else {
            Util.ShowToastMessage(getActivity(), R.string.internet_connection);
        }
    }
```

This api is getting called successfully, I have checked it in logcat. But after it the user is not redirected to intended screen.

Comment: Hey Umang,

Please post the code that you have an issue with.

Comment: Post your AndroidManifest.xml file and also which API level are you testing on .

Comment: hey @JamesPalfrey I have update the code which is being used for login where I'm having problem in my project, please check it out.

Comment: @SurajBahadur I am not sure if I can post  AndroidManifest.xml file sorry, but I can tell you following details I have in the project : minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30

        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
        versionCode 25
        versionName "1.4.2"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner" ,i dont change these things for testing or at the time of production. Android studiogradle version is :4.2.1

Comment: @UmangUpadhyay Please check the answer and let me know if it work or not

Comment: Hey @SurajBahadur I will do the change you suggested, but I have a doubt wouldn't setting the minifyEnabled false will increase the app size which is less as of now  because of minifyEnabled true ?

Answer (score 2):

The possible reason for this behavior could be because of proguard rules set in the `build.gradle` file

Change `minifyEnabled true` to `minifyEnabled false`

**Note:**

1. Proguard is a free Java class file shrinker, optimizer, obfuscator, and preverifier. It detects and removes unused classes, fields, methods, and attributes. Mobile app development companies use proguard in android , it optimizes bytecode and removes unused instructions.
2. This is a temporary solution and you need to manually figure out the error when `minifiyEnable` is `true`.

Comment: Hey @SurajBahadur I will do the change you suggested, but I have a doubt wouldn't setting the minifyEnabled false will increase the app size which is less as of now because of minifyEnabled true ?

Comment: When you change the status to true, You can see the error on the logcat while calling the API. Once you fixed then you can use the proguard rule.

Comment: I have minifyEnabled true in AndroidManifest.xml file, I can see some information in logcat when I connect the app from play store with my Android studio, problem is when the api call is made, there is no error or exception in that particular api call, this is the problem I am facing.